# I want to get indexpath.row on next view after tableview or any other alternative

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, ios5

i am kind of making app which play audio using table view

After selecting particular row,it play audio on next view,but it does not solve my problem

Since want it to stop after dismissing the view and return to table view

So i want a way to play song on next view in such a way it stops after dismissing the view

or,

if i can access to the particular row(indexpathy.row) on next view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just property synthesize the raw no or int value to the nextview like bellow..

```
@interface NextViewController : UIViewController{
     int rowNo;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) int rowNo;
```

and synthesize in .m file like bellow...

```
@synthesize rowNo;
```

and when you push to nextview at that time set this property like this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NextViewController *objNextViewController = [[NextViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"NextViewController" bundle:nil];
   objNextViewController.rowNo = indexPath.row;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objNextViewController animated:YES];
    [NextViewController release];
}
```

Comment: Hello,Thanks for the help.

This part i understand.Maybe i am did not explain correctly.

Now in next view how to use row no?
or i can get to know which row was selected in my next view
i am not found of nsuserdefault,is there any way to get it beside nsuserdefault.
Since i want to play particular audio file on each row

Comment: yes mate if you have an array then you can easily use this variable like [yourArray objectOfIndex:rowNo];.. and play the vedio with array index.. i hope you understand, and yes you can set userdefault and see the code for it from my blog with this link.. http://parasjoshi3.blogspot.in/2012/06/store-array-in-userdefaults-and-also.html

Comment: Thanks for your code and advice,it was really help full.
I found other way for working using your above code...

Comment: yes dude i'll give u all solution which i solved for u dude.. i'll try to help in your every problem if occurred dude.. :)

Comment: I want your help in other question ,can u again provide your help

Answer (score 0):

Simply take a variable in the next view's class and pass in the value of indexpath.row to it when you are selecting the cell. Since this variable has the value of row selected, you can access this value in next view.